# Nuxt.js with passport losing req.user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to make Node.js app with Nuxt.js and Passport.js.
I login and set user data in vuex.

action:

```
nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session && req.session.authUser) {
        commit('SET_USER', req.session.authUser)
    }
}
```

mutation:

```
SET_USER: function (state, user) {
    state.authUser = user
}
```

And it works fine, but when I tried to access page that can be accessed only by loged in user there came problems.

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/articles/add')

router.get('/api/articles/add', ensureAuthenticated,
 (req, res) => {
    res.send({
        title: 'Add Article'
    })
})

function ensureAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    } else {
        res.redirect('/users/login')
    }
}
```

I login and go to http://localhost:3000/articles/add, make request for data restricted for this user (GET http://localhost:3000/api/articles/add). Checking by `ensureAuthenticated` if user is loged in and `isAuthenticated()` returns `false` all the time and when I want to send user data without `ensureAuthenticated` it's returning `undefined`

```
app.get('/api/articles/add', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user) // undefined
})
```

BUT if I will send this data to the same api route as page, which I want access, I'm getting right data on screen.

```
app.get('/articles/add', function(req, res) {
    res.send(req.user) // {...}
})
```

Can someone explain me that? And in some situation I can't make redirection from node.js side. Like in this prev example

```
function ensureAuthenticated (req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next()
    } else {
        res.redirect('/users/login') // ignored
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the answer :) 
https://github.com/nuxt-community/express-template/blob/master/protected-ssr-api.md



_The moment you start dealing with user session, you'll notice that protected routes will reject nuxt requests when running from the server. This is because when nuxt is ran from the server, the browser cookie is lost._